# Safe use of eval() or alternatives - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm always weary of using eval in any language but I can't think of a better way to do 2 things.  From everything I've read evAl is evIl (that was bad).  Any thoughts are appreciated.
I have module with a dictionary that either calls a function or sets an attribute depending on how you call it from another module

```
module Config
some_dict = {1: ["desc 1", "callfunction1()"], 
  2: ["desc2", "setattr(object, "attribute", "the fun things"]}
```

etc

```
module other
try:
  i = int(input())
  eval(Config.some_dict[i][1])
except ValueError:
  print("nope")
```

I'm just wondering if there is a safer way to do this.
Also if I'm trying to debug while the program is running:

```
try:
  eval(input())
except:
  pass
```

Is this acceptable or pythonic or is there a better way?  I'm new to python (I run mostly JSL so everything is done with eval(parse()).

Comment: If you're trying to execute arbitrary code, you have to use `eval`. If you can narrow down for us the domain of what your configuration can do.

Comment: Cool.  It's effective for what I'm using it for and it definitely won't be in the final product so I guess I'm okay with using it for now.

Answer (score 6):

There is a much better way: Use first-class functions.

```
def func2():
    setattr(object, "attribute", "the fun things")

some_dict = {
    1: ["desc 1", callfunction1],
    2: ["desc2", func2]
}

i = int(input())
Config.some_dict[i][1]()
```

The clutter can be reduced using `lambda` or `partial`, if you're comfortable with them.
That said, your existing solution isn't as bad as many uses of `eval`, because it doesn't evaluate arbitrary user input but rather hard-coded strings. It's just plain unnecessary, pretty slow, and ugly.

And for debugging, there are dedicated debuggers. They work better than an ad-hoc eval-loop.

Comment: Is there a good way if they take different arguments or different number of arguments?  say callfunction1(takes1, takes2) and func2(other1)? I feel if I'm doing this then the setup for the reasoning should be relooked at (I'm not doing this by the way, just a thought).

Comment: @Faller Where do the arguments come from? If they're constant, do what I did with `setattr`. If they vary - where do they come from and how do you know which functions takes which arguments? That probably leads to another piece of data to include in `some_dict`, or perhaps you can get away with passing all data to all functions (each functions would ignore the things it doesn't need).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend making your dictionary values into callables of some sort. For example,

```
some_dict = {
    1: ["desc 1", callfunction1], 
    2: ["desc2", lambda: setattr(object, "attribute", "the fun things")]
}
```

Then when you want to use elements from your dictionary, just call them :

```
name, func = some_dict[1]
func()
```

The important thing is that each value in the dictionary needs to have the same calling interface (e.g., takes no arguments).

Comment: This is very good example, for a way to avoid using eval.I wil just requote from somewhere: Eval is a bad practice, Just to name a few reasons:

    There is almost always a better way to do it,
    Very dangerous and insecure,
    Makes debugging difficult,
    Slow

Answer (score 0):

You can store functions as values in a dictionary, so just create a function for each operation, look it up in the dictionary, and call it.

```
def set_object_attr(obj=object, name='attribute', value='the fun things'):
    setattr(obj, name, value)

some_dict = {1: ["desc 1", callfunction1],
             2: ["desc 2", set_object_attr]}

# then wherever you are using this
some_dict[i][1]()
```

As you can see here, since `callfunction1` is already a function you do not need to wrap it in another call.  You need to wrap the `setattr()` call because you need to be able to call the function without any arguments.

I wrote the `set_object_attr` function above to make it clear what is going on, but in this case it would be better to use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools
some_dict = {1: ["desc 1", callfunction1],
             2: ["desc 2", functools.partial(setattr, object,
                                             'attribute', 'the fun things')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
some_dict[2]['function'] = setattr
some_dict[2]['options'] = [object, "attribute", "value"]
```

Then,

```
if option = 'foo':
   some_dict[2]['function'](*some_dict[2]['options'])
```